# Override SaveChangesAsync en EF Core entra en un bucle sin terminar

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Intento grabar otras entidades luego de que se detecte la creación de un entidad .Para ello he sobre escrito `SaveChangesAsync` desde el DbContext

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
            await OnAfterSaveChanges();
            return result;
        }
```

En `OnAfterSaveChanges()`filtro la entidad que se creo.

***Lógica***

La lógica debería se así : Cada vez que se cree un **Nuevo Items** , crear un registro **"Inventories"** y cada vez que se cree un Inventories se cree un **InventoryKardex** , parecido a los service provider de laravel , no encontrado algo mas especifico , pero si existe algo mejor porfavor háganmelo saber.

***Metodo OnAfterSaveChange***

```
  private Task OnAfterSaveChanges()
{
    var itemsAddeds = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x=>x.Entity is Items);
    foreach (var itemsAdded in itemsAddeds)
    {
        var item = itemsAdded.Entity as Items;
        if (item != null)
        {
            Inventories inventory = new Inventories()
            {
                Type = "1",
                Description = "Stock inicial",
                WarehouseId = (int)item.WarehouseId,
                WarehouseDestinationId = (int)item.WarehouseId,
                Quantity = item.Stock != null ? (decimal)item.Stock : 0,
                ItemId = item.Id,
            };

            Inventories.Add(inventory);
        }

    }
    

    var inventoriesAddeds = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is Inventories );
    foreach (var inventoriesAdded in inventoriesAddeds)
    {
        var inventory = inventoriesAdded.Entity as Inventories;
        var inventoryKardex = new InventoryKardex()
        {
            DateOfIssue = DateTime.Now,
            ItemId = inventory.ItemId,
            WarehouseId = inventory.WarehouseId,
            Quantity = inventory.Quantity,
            InventoryKardexableType = inventory.Description,

        };

        InventoryKardex.Add(inventoryKardex);
    }
    
    if (itemsAddeds == null || inventoriesAddeds == null || !itemsAddeds.Any() || !inventoriesAddeds.Any())
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    return SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

***Error***

Básicamente **entra en un bucle infinito en OnAfterSaveChanges()** , sin saber si esa entidad ya paso y se genera una excepción no contralada

Comment: En el metodo `SaveChangesAsync` haces la llamada siguiente `await OnAfterSaveChanges();` llamas al metodo `OnAfterSaveChanges` pero luego en este metodo  incliuyes la linea `return SaveChangesAsync();` que llama al metodo `SaveChangesAsync` de nuevo, en tu código es mas que evidente que si surge el bucle infinito, es por que la condición `if (itemsAddeds == null || inventoriesAddeds == null || !itemsAddeds.Any() || !inventoriesAddeds.Any())` no se está cumpliendo en ninguno de los casos, seria muy complejo revisar por que ocurre esto sin tener el resto del codigo de la aplicación

Comment: @EduardoReyes si claro es evidente , por eso detalle cual es el error , pero no se como detectar si la entidad ya paso , porque siempre llegan la misma, cual resto de codigo podria agregar ?

Comment: Pero ademas, ahora me doy cuenta que tu primera linea dentro del metodo `SaveChangesAsync` se esta llamando a si mismo, de esta forma el bucle seria interminable en todos los casos. Esta linea llama al propio metodo de forma recursiva `var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);`